# compare two successive hasmap value

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I need to compare for a single hashmap two by two successive values like in the example below:

key is: Nature   ----  Value is: 2

key is: duck   ----  Value is: 3

key is: sheep   ----  Value is: 3

key is: WoodTable   ----  Value is: 4

key is: PVCdoor   ----  Value is: 4

What I'm asking for, is how can I compare :

- the value of Nature with the value of duck
- the value of duck of the value of sheep
- the value of sheep with the value of woodTable
- the value of woodTable with the value of PVCdoor

.... etc

I tried but I can't get the result I need. Please if you have any idea I need your help;
This is the function I use but the result isn't at all what I need as an output.

Thank you

```
public Map<String, Integer> setCoefffils(Map<String, Integer> map){

        Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry=map.entrySet().iterator().next();



     this.listCoeffConceptfilsfinal.put(entry.getKey(), coeffFils);

         Set<Entry<String, Integer>> setHm = map.entrySet();

         java.util.Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> it = setHm.iterator();


               Entry<String, Integer> e = it.next();

               for( Entry<String, Integer> ee : setHm){
                 //  Entry<String, Integer> eeee = it.next();
                  // for( Entry<String, Integer> eeee : setHm){
                   System.out.println("key current is: "+ee.getKey() + "   ----  Value is: " + ee.getValue());
                   System.out.println("key following is: "+e.getKey() + "   ----  Value is: " + e.getValue());
               if(ee.getValue().equals(e.getValue()))
                   System.out.println(""+ee.getValue() + "   et   " + e.getValue()+" sont égaux ");
               else 
                   System.out.println(" ne sont pas égaux ");

          //  }



return this.listCoeffConceptfilsfinal;


        }
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be after comparison of such elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to store all the keys in a list, then access them one after the other.

```
public static void foo(Map<String, Integer> map) {
    Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();
    String lastKey = null;
    for (String key : keySet) {
        if (null == lastKey) {
            lastKey = key;
            continue;
        }
        if (map.get(key).equals(map.get(lastKey))) {
            System.out.println("Les valeurs associées aux clés " + lastKey + " et " + key + " sont égales.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Les valeurs associées aux clés " + lastKey + " et " + key + " sont différentes.");
        }
        lastKey = key;
    }
}
```

But be aware : Maps doesn't always guarantee that the keys stay in insertion order. Thus, your comparison could be false. If you want to conserve insertion order, you have to use a LinkedHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

**With key order**

**CODE:**

```
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;
/**
 * Write a description of class sumAndMax here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class compareMap
{

    public static void main(String[] args){
         Map<String, Integer> map = initializeMap();
         compareMaps(map);
    }

    private static void compareMaps(
        Map<String, Integer> map)
        {
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            String leftKey = "";
            String rightKey = "";
            int leftValue = -1;
            int rightValue = -1;

            while (it.hasNext()) {

                //  Get values
                Map.Entry<String, Integer> pair = it.next();
                leftKey = rightKey;
                leftValue = rightValue;
                rightKey = pair.getKey();
                rightValue = pair.getValue();

                if(!leftKey.equals("")){    
                    //  Compare keys
                    System.out.println("Comparing key "+leftKey+" with key "+rightKey);
                    System.out.println("Result: "+leftKey.equals(rightKey));

                    //  Compare values
                    System.out.println("Comparing value "+leftValue+" with value "+rightValue);
                    System.out.println("Result: "+(leftValue==rightValue));
                }

            }

        }

   private static Map<String, Integer> initializeMap(){
       //   Use Tree map for have a key ordered map !!!
       Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
       map.put("keyA",3);
       map.put("keyB",4);
       map.put("keyC",8);
       map.put("keyD",8);
       map.put("keyE",89);
       map.put("keyF",4);
       map.put("keyG",4);
       return map;
    }
}
```

**RESULT:**

```
Comparing key keyA with key keyB
Result: false
Comparing value 3 with value 4
Result: false
Comparing key keyB with key keyC
Result: false
Comparing value 4 with value 8
Result: false
Comparing key keyC with key keyD
Result: false
Comparing value 8 with value 8
Result: true
Comparing key keyD with key keyE
Result: false
Comparing value 8 with value 89
Result: false
Comparing key keyE with key keyF
Result: false
Comparing value 89 with value 4
Result: false
Comparing key keyF with key keyG
Result: false
Comparing value 4 with value 4
Result: true
```